# Ubuntu 16.04 login screen in loop after installing AMD radeon driver

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

My laptop is an HP 14-AM118TX with a AMD Radeon R5 M430.

Before I installed the driver only black screen was visible with an AMD error message. After installing the driver the login screen is visible but I cannot login! `tty`s 1 through 6 are accessible to me but I cannot login.

After I enter the password, the "System problem detected" window is displayed and the login screen appears again.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: i too have same issue, with my dell. its frustrating. op can you add more to tag to amd?

Comment: @Gunnrryy You have the same graphics card? Can you tell me what the "AMD error message" which OP refers to is?

Comment: @Gunnrryy    The output of `uname -a` would also be useful along with `sudo lshw -C display`

Answer (score 1):

At Login Screen

ALT + CTRL + F2

type your username and password. Create a new user.

```
sudo adduser username
```

new password for the user.

ALT + CTRL + F7

login from new user you created.If worked you need to delete all the files related to your login in your home dir.

like .gconf , .gnome, .gnome2 and so on if not imp.

And will work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I have quite a bit of experience with this issue from installing nVidia drivers (for high end GPUs like GTX 1070).

The only way I found around it, is the **order** of installation:

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Check both 'Canonical Partner' under 'Other Software' tab.
3. Check 'Pre-released updates' under 'Developer Options' tab.
4. Click 'Close' and 'Reload'.
5. After the window disappears, run a full upgrade of the system (apt upgrade, apt autoremove).
6. Restart.
7. After the reboot, search for 'Drivers' and choose the latest available, apply the changes and wait for it to finish installing.
8. Restart again.

You Ubuntu box should be using the correct AMD driver now...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with my nVidia Optimus laptop. The only way I could fix it was to purge the system of the nvidia drivers and the Bumblebee GPU switching package by pressing Crtl + Alt + F2, login, and then running:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia.* bumblebee
```

Perhaps you should try purging the AMD drivers and then installing the one you need.

Comment: They’re asking about AMD not nVidia.

Comment: Which is why I wrote "Perhaps you should try purging the AMD drivers and then installing the one you need."

Comment: but gave a command to purge the nVidia drivers.

Comment: I said I had the same problem using nVidia and showed the command I used to fix it. I then suggested that using the same command for the AMD drivers, the name of which I don't know, might fix the OP's problem. I was trying to be helpful, what is wrong with that?